# Anyone know of a Ruby SQL parser?

Tags: sql, ruby

Anyone know of a Ruby SQL parser?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a SQL parser done with rparsec:

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JPARSEC/SQL+parser+in+rparsec

Answer (score 1):

[this](http://pivotalrb.rubyforge.org/svn/sql_parser) is the svn tree for a sql parser based on Treetop

Comment: The SQL parser proposed by corprew, which is based on treetop, can only parse SELECT statements

Answer (score 1):

I post answer here for someone who will need. I found this gem  'sql-parser'

```
gem install sql-parser
```

However this gem is not up-to-date if you install with command 'gem install'. So we have to check out the code from github also to get latest version. When I try to parse an insert statement after gem install. It failed.

After updating code from github. it can parse.

Github
https://github.com/cryodex/sql-parser

Answer (score 1):

Try the gda gem by tenderlove.

RubyGems: https://rubygems.org/gems/gda

Github: https://github.com/tenderlove/gda/