# MySQL SQL/DDL parser/validator in Ruby (on Rails)

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ddl

I am looking for a tool or a library for Rails to validate/parse queries that could be SQL and/or DDL. Currently, I did not find anything that I could use quickly and easily.

I found [Parslet](http://kschiess.github.com/parslet) that I can use to define my own SQL/DDL language to validate SQL/DDL statements.

The goal to reach is to have a tool that we can use to validate the SQL/DDL syntax before any run on the database. For example, DDL queries are not transactional with MySQL and therefore, if one statement fails at the middle of a bigger script, we need to restore the database or run the script from the failure point (that is not really userfriendly). If we can, at least, validate the syntax, we will improve our daily work by removing a lot of "stupid" errors.

Answer (score 2):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2488791/1177119) lists a few Ruby SQL parsers you might be interested in taking a look at. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2489105/1177119) in particular has a Treetop grammar file you could probably use as a base for your own validations.

Comment: I seen these posts but they cover only part of SQL (SELECT query) and that's all. Unfornatelly, it is really far that I look for but a, as you said, a starting point for further work. Currently, I try to work with Parslet and create my proper grammar rule file but it is really a big task and require a lot of spec definition to go throuhg all the statements. On the other side, the advantage is that I can add some enforcement to the SQL standard to enforce some internal rules to avoid "stupid" mistakes.